# How to change the default RN 0.71 Typescript to javascript

Tags: react-native

I was new to react native and i want to create the react native project with JavaScript, but whenever i create a project with react native 0.71, not the expo... it gets created with typescript, is there any way we can change it to JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Native now ships with TypeScript automatically with version [0.71](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/01/03/typescript-first).

I highly recommend using TypeScript though, since it can make programming react-native projects more pleasant and has many advantages.

However, if you want to stay on JavaScript, you can convert the pre-created components to `.js` instead of `.tsx` and remove all types used.

Comment: what all the packages needs to be removed from package json and is there any package needs to installed after removing any package from package.json

Comment: You don't have to install any packages. And if you want to remove any packages, remove anything that contains `@types` in the devDependencies if any exists.

Comment: With yarn
yarn remove @tsconfig/react-native
With NPM
npm uninstall @tsconfig/react-native